# Nested attributes with multiple associations to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, model-associations

Lets suppose I have a question and answer model, such that a question has many answers.

**Question Class**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :correct_answer, class_name: 'Answer'
  has_many :answers, class_name: 'Answer'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :correct_answer, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Answer class**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I want to be able to create answers nested in questions. For example:

```
@question = Question.new(:content => 'How many legs does a dog have?', correct_answer_attributes: {:content => '4'})
```

**The Issue**

When I do this for correct_answer (like above), an answer and a correct_answer is created. How can I get just a correct_answer to be created?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :correct_answer, class_name: 'CorrectAnswer'
  ....
 end
```

Then

```
 class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
 end
```

Then

```
 class CorrectAnswer < Answer
 end
```

Then send param `type`

```
 @question = Question.new(:content => 'How many legs does a dog have?', answer_attributes: {:content => '4', :type => CorrectAnswer})
```

Comment: You're answer was nearly correct. I tried what you recommended and it didn't work. The only problem was the last part. ```@question = Question.new(:content => 'How many legs does a dog have?', correct_answer_attributes: {:content => '4'})``` worked. If you update this ill choose your answer.

Comment: Sorry, i've made a mistake, once I save the record the answer is still created :(

Comment: you need to send `type` for this STI

Comment: Its expecting data in the following format for answers_attributes: ```:answers_attributes => {:1419841211486 => {:content => "test"}}```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by changing the relationship of the answer from a `has_one` to a `belongs_to`:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    belongs_to :accepted_answer, :class_name => "Answer", 
                                 :foreign_key => :answer_id
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```